# Preact and React in a single project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I work on a huge React code base having multiple packages. I want to try to migrate the components of a single package to Preact and rest continue with react components. How to achieve this kind of programming pattern?

What all steps do we have to follow?

How to ensure smooth communication in the case of

```
 <ReactComponent>
     <PreactComponent>
          <ReactComponent/>
      </PreactComponent>
   </ReactComponent>
```

Project Structure is of like: Lets consider we have to convert package2 react components to preact and then use React components with packages of 1 and 3.

```
ProjectName
| - packages
|   | - package1 (React)
|   |   |- package.json
|   | - package2  (Preact)
|   |   |- package.json
|   | - package3  (React)
|   |   |- package.json
| - package.json
```

Comment: Which module bundler are you using? (webpack, vite, ...)

Comment: probably using webpack. I am unable to figure out this, how can we check what bundler the project is using?

Comment: Look for files in the root of your project that have "webpack" or "vite" in the name, so like "webpack.config.js".

Comment: we are using webpack.config.js

Answer (score 1):

In order to make this work easily, without introducing concepts like Micro Frontends, use the official [preact/compat](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/switching-to-preact) package.

This package lets you use both Preact and React components at the same time, by adding a thin (atm 2kB) layer which makes React components compatible with your growing Preact codebase.

To set this up, you have to:

1. Uninstall your react packages
2. Install preact
3. If you use webpack, rollup, parcel, [you have to alias](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/getting-started#aliasing-react-to-preact) react -> preact, so that your ES6 imports to `react` and `react-dom` still work. If you use Vite, you have to [use different plugin for preact](https://puruvj.dev/blog/moving-macos-from-react-to-preact-vite).

#### Edit:

If you can't use `preact/compat`, you will have to integrate you package differently with the rest of the project through a technique called [Micro Frontends](https://martinfowler.com/articles/micro-frontends.html). This techniques allows teams to work independently (also technology-wise) on separate applications that you can then put together into a bigger whole.

Using this approach, you'd either have to distribute your package as Web Component, embed it via `<iframe>` or distribute as a JS package that you then manually mount onto an HTML element of your choice.

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer. In which packages in above example, do we have to uninstall react packages. (package2 here?). Also, our package2 just has the package.json file along with src code. Where do we have to configure the preact/compat changes? We don't have the webpack config files in each package?

Comment: Depends on the structure of your project. If you have mono repo, where all the packages have common dependencies (node_modules) then you have to uninstall them only in the root project. If your projects are separate, then you have to do it for each where you want to switch to preact.

Comment: We have webpack.config.js defined only for a package which we consider the main entry point for the application. And, rest all the packages we are building by including them in the build script of this main package.

So, in this case I can uninstall the react packages of the package which we want to migrate to preact, but where do i have to alias react -> preact? i mean which file

Comment: The alias config, which I linked in my answer, belongs to `webpack.config.js` then.

Comment: If I do this alias config change in the webpack.config.js of the main package, does it mean I am migrating my whole project into Preact? Where as I just want to migrate a single package which my team owns

Comment: Ok I thought you want migrate the whole project eventually, don't you? If you don't, is it even a good idea to not use React still? Is that package of your gonna be used outside of the main project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253625/discussion-between-madhu-kumar-tallapalli-and-dan-macak).

Comment: Just adding that there is no inherent compatibility between React and Preact components. React cannot render Preact components and the reverse is also true. While you can alias react to preact/compat, that is still Preact in use; it's a specific tool that allows consuming the React interface in Preact.